# [] method of Ruby String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, monkeypatching

When I reading source code of Beast, I found a lot of code like this:

```
<%= 'Password'[:password_title] %>
```

It seems like a call to [] method with Symbol as input parameter to a String to me, but I didn't find such type of parameter of String [] method in the ruby API. What is this means?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a method added by the "Gibberish" plug-in Beast uses, for internationalization. Remember, classes in Ruby are open, so you can't always count on the standard API in cases like this!

Answer (score 4):

In beast source, check out the gibberish plugin where String class is being modified to accept symbols in brackets function.

String class by itself does not do anything reasonable by applying `str[symbol]` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
str[fixnum] => fixnum or nil
str[fixnum, fixnum] => new_str or nil
str[range] => new_str or nil
str[regexp] => new_str or nil
str[regexp, fixnum] => new_str or nil
str[other_str] => new_str or nil
```

These are what I found. If the symbol here is equals to String, I still don't understand the meaning of the code. Why not simply use:

```
<%= 'password' %>
```

or even:

```
password
```

Comment: Yes, it's a bit strange. I'll delete my answer. I didn't think before I offered it.